# Создание desktop приложения с помощью JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, jar, java-9

Всем привет!
Написал небольшой калькулятор под пк через JavaFX, теперь хочу, чтобы запускалось оно по двойному клику мыши с помощью jar упаковки.
Сюда я совершенно не сразу пошел писать, а сделал очень много всего, вплоть до переустановки самой Java.
Итак, с чего я начинал? Как я добавлял JavaFX библиотеку в проект? С помощью intellij idea я в структуре проекта добавил библиотеку JavaFX, НЕ через maven. Далее в конфигурации я указал VM options, таким образом, в идее проект стал запускаться. Точно так же с помощью идеи я добавил и артефакт для создания jar. Тогда я радостно перехожу к моему любимому jar и в тот же момент становится печально от того, что моя версия java 8 слишком старая, чтобы запустить мой jar. Я переустановил java не сразу, но да, снова пересобрал jar и вижу, что данный тип файлов перестал распознаваться (текущая версия - JDK 15), в прочем эта проблема не сильно важна на основе главной, но как это исправить? Чтобы win снова видел jar. Я особого внимания этой проблеме не стал уделять и запустил мой jar через командную строку командой java -jar PATH.jar
Тут я вижу новую ошибку:
ERROR: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
Пробовал исправлять проблему следующим образом по совету сообщества stackoverflow

```
class MainLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main.main(args);
    } 
}
```

Увы, всё равно ничего не помогло, ошибка та же.
Еще немного сведений:
java version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)
Устанавливал java с офф сайта oracle
Также устанавливал javafx-sdk-11.0.2 с сайта Gluon
Еще раз повторю, что VM options есть и он такой:
--module-path PATH --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

**ЕСЛИ ЛЕНЬ ЧИТАТЬ ;)**

1. Как сделать так, чтобы Windows 10 отображала jar файлы как jar приложения, а не zip пакеты
2. Как исправить ошибку ERROR: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

*советую лучше прочитать всё, что я описал, там сказано то, о чем я помню, что делал)))*

Также хочу попросить, если можно, пример с кодом (необязательно с функционалом), где jar приложение будет запускаться либо кликом мыши, либо через командную строку

Заранее всем, ну, просто огромейнешее спасибо, кто решит эту проблему, иии, да, мне JavaFX актуальна, так что без глупых ответов

**ERROR: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application**

Код класса Main, вряд-ли понадобится, но все же:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 406, 477));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Как исправить ошибку ERROR: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Если Java <=8 запуск производится по стандартной схеме:

```
java -jar myprogram.jar
```

Если Java >= 9 начинаются проблемы. Немного теории: в Java 9 введено понятие модулей - по сути это некая надстройка на пакетной организацией классов. Пакеты теперь объединены в модули, описание модуля выносится в специальный файл `module-info.java` - [документация](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Ближе к сути. JavaFX начиная с Java 9 вынесен теперь в отдельный модуль (на самом деле в модули), которые не входят в состав JDK, путь к ним надо указывать отдельно через `module-path` (грубый аналог `CLASSPATH` для модулей). Механизм такой:

1. Скачиваем JavaFX для вашей платформы [на сайте](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)
2. Устанавливаем, например путь пусть будет `PATH_TO_JAVA_FX`
3. Теперь запуск делаем так:

```
java --module-path PATH_TO_JAVA_FX --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH -jar myprogram.jar
```

### Как сделать так, чтобы Windows 10 отображала jar файлы как jar приложения

Взять ваш JAR, нажать правую кнопку мыши выбрать *properties/свойства*, далее нажать кнопку *application/приложение* и выбрать в списке Java (вместо архиватора).

Comment: Здравствуйте! В intellij idea поставил 1.8jdk, при попытке сборки проекта как через maven, так и без, при помощи билда артефакта получается jar, который выкидывает такое исключение Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application \\\ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application

Comment: По-моему это баг артефакта IDEA. Я собираю "толстый" JAR с помощью gradle и все работает.

Comment: не, это не баг, я просто тупанул, у меня на пк 15 jdk стояло

Comment: С этого места подробнее, я так и не смог собрать рабочий JAR с помощью встроенного JavaFX артефакта IDEA - расскажите что и как вы сделали?

Comment: в IntelliJ IDEA jdk 1.8 Amazon \\ на пк java 8 https://www.oracle.com/ru/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html собирал с помощью фреймворка maven, там вручную добавил классы Main и Controller в папке src\main\java и в src\main\resources добавил fxml, дальше в методе main - Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml")); ну и в артефактах обычный JAR со всеми зависимостями

Comment: а нет, вру, этот проект был src\sample и все файлы тут, все остальное так же